# How to get the selected node items from jQuery checkbox tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am using jQuery to generate the checkbox tree, I am not able to get the checked node from tree list. Please help me on this.

Here is my code:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<!--
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tabs').tabs({
            cookie: { expires: 30 }
        });
        $('.jquery').each(function() {
            eval($(this).html());
        });
        $('.button').button();
    });
    //-->
</script>
```

## jQuery checkboxTree plugin demo

Project Home

```
<code class="jquery" lang="text/javascript">
    $('#tree1').checkboxTree({
    initializeUnchecked: 'collapsed',
    collapse: function(){
            alert('collapse event triggered (passed as option)');
    },
    expand: function(){
            alert('expand event triggered (passed as option)');
    },
    check: function(n){
           alert('Hi there!!!'+n);
    },
    uncheck: function(n){
            alert('Hi there!!!'+n);
    }
    });
</code>
<ul id="tree1">
    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 1</label>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 1.1</label>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 1.1.1</label>
                </ul>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 1.2</label>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 1.2.1</label>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 1.2.2</label>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 1.2.3</label>
                        <ul>
                            <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 1.2.3.1</label>
                            <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 1.2.3.2</label>
                        </ul>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 1.2.4</label>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 1.2.5</label>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 1.2.6</label>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2</label>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.1</label>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.1.1</label>
                </ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.2</label>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.2.1</label>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.2.2</label>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.2.3</label>
                        <ul>
                            <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.2.3.1</label>
                            <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.2.3.2</label>
                        </ul>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.2.4</label>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.2.5</label>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Node 2.2.6</label>
                </ul>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

Please do help me on this.

Comment: First, get rid of that eval(). it's evil and WILL kick your dog for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use the [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector. The following should return any checked checkboxes in the tree1 element.

```
var checkedCheckboxes = $('#tree1 input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
```

Comment: Hi mcNux, Thanks a lot for your valuable help, could you please tell me how should i display particular checkbox name using "checkedCheckboxes" ? i tried using checkedCheckboxes.id and checkedCheckboxes.value but both were not working.

Comment: I suggest you refer to [jQuery documention](http://docs.jquery.com/) as everything you need to know is on there. You will need to understand Selectors and the attr() method to achieve what you want.